# Как создавать неопределенное количество переменных при передаче в функцию PHP

Tags: php

Есть массив с переменными

```
$data = ['peer_id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1, 'message' => 'Текст'];
```

Нужна функция, которая будет создавать переменные переданные в нее, значения для переменных он должен брать из global $data

```
getData($id, $user_id, $message);
print($id);
```

Причем можно задать только нужные переменные, например

```
getData($id, $message);
```

UPDATE: решил остановится на такой реализации

```php
public function initVars(&$id = null, &$message = null, &$payload = null) {
    $id = ...;
    $message = ...;
    $payload = ...; 
}
```

Comment: В данной формулировке это звучит как "помогите выстрелить мне в ногу". В вопросе необходимо написать, почему вы вдруг решили что вам надо создавать переменные и брать их из глобального массива. И тогда вам объяснят, как делать правильно

Comment: Пишу библиотеку для работы с vk api. Вк отправляет callback запрос с данными о новом событии, в принципе тут глобалить не нужно, просто внутри функции уже есть доступ к этим данным. Сейчас реализация такая:
`list($user_id, $id, $message) = $vk->getData('user_id, peer_id, message');`
А хотелось бы
`$vk->getData($user_id, $id, $message);`

Comment: [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php) экспортирует ключи массива в переменные, но подход весьма сомнителен.

Comment: Вопрос только в том, как передать N количество переменных в функцию, при том, что их еще надо создать

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть на `Splat Operator` типа `троеточие` или еще известный как `unpacking operator`, думаю это даст вам идей, как это можно сделать, так как он позволяет передавать в функцию неопределенное количество параметров. По поводу фильтрации нужных или недопустимых параметров, думаю это придется делать внутри функции

Comment: @zippp да не нужно ему передавать неизвестные параметры, у него совсем другая проблема, которую он просто сформулировать не может. И сплат не про передачу неизвестного количества, это можно и без него

Comment: @zippp да, спасибо, думаю это лучшее решение. Напиши коммент как ответ на вопрос, добавлю его как решение

Comment: @КириллМиновский сорь, мне лень :) все норм, просто читай доки и пользуйся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Важно! Скорее всего делать то, что вы задумали не надо. Вся эта затея выглядит очень подозрительно. Но если это учебный пример или вам просто интересно возможно ли такое в php, то предлагаю вашему вниманию такой вариант.

При решении такой задачки возникает несколько трудностей.

Первая -- получить имя переменной, с которой вызвали функцию. Действительно клёвого метода сделать это, мне не известно. Но можно подглядеть в бэктрейсе строчку, в которой вызывалась функция и распарсить её. Это весьма паршивый метод, но для учебных задач или дебага его можно использовать.

```
function initVar() {
    // получаем имя переменной (так лучше не делать)
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT | DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1);
    $fileName = $backtrace[0]['file'];
    $file = file($fileName); // загружаем файл, в котором был вызов нашей функции
    $lineNum = $backtrace[0]['line'];
    $code = $file[$lineNum - 1];
    $matches = [];
    preg_match('~initVar\s*\(\s*\$(?<varName>\w+)~', $code, $matches); // парсим php
    $varName = $matches['varName']; 
}
```

Вторая проблема это, как присваивать переменные. Это просто, для этого существуют ссылки.

```
function initVar(&$var) {
    // получаем имя переменной (так лучше не делать)
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT | DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1);
    $fileName = $backtrace[0]['file'];
    $file = file($fileName); // загружаем файл, в котором был вызов нашей функции
    $lineNum = $backtrace[0]['line'];
    $code = $file[$lineNum - 1];
    $matches = [];
    preg_match('~initVar\s*\(\s*\$(?<varName>\w+)~', $code, $matches); // парсим php
    $varName = $matches['varName'];

    // находим переменную в глобальном $data
    global $data;
    $var = $data[$varName]?? null;
}
```

И третья проблема это несколько аргументов. Тут тоже просто.

```
function initVar(&...$vars) {
    // получаем имя переменной (так лучше не делать)
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT | DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1);
    $fileName = $backtrace[0]['file'];
    $file = file($fileName); // загружаем файл, в котором был вызов нашей функции
    $lineNum = $backtrace[0]['line'];
    $code = $file[$lineNum - 1];
    $matches = [];
    preg_match('~initVar\s*\(\s*(?<varNames>[^)]+)~', $code, $matches);
    $varNames = explode(',', $matches['varNames']);

    global $data;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($vars as &$var) {
        $var = $data[trim($varNames[$i++], ' $')]?? null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Получения имен переменных выглядит действительно не очень, хотел использовать это решение на проде. Оставлю решение через list или то, что update моего вопроса

Answer (score 3):

Так НИКОГДА не делают. Это запутывание собственного кода.

`getData($user_id, $id, $message);` - это передача параметров **в функцию**. Любой программист будет читать это именно так.

Вам же надо получать переменные **из функции**. и существующий подход, с `list($user_id, $id, $message)` является оптимальным, если надо прям обязательно получать переменные. Хотя в данном случае переменные являются худшим вариантом.

Не нужно пытаться облегчить себе жизнь таким способом. то, что имена переменных похожи на имена параметров, переданных в API - это просто совпадение.

Если функция возвращает неизвестное количество значений, она должна возвращать массив.
Если надо обращаться к возвращаемам переменным по именам, то функция должна возвращать **ассоциативный массив**.

поэтому

```
$data = $vk->getData('user_id, peer_id, message');
echo $data['message'];
```

это единственный правильный вариант

Comment: Считаешь, что preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches) тоже запутывает свой код, потому что результат записывает в $matches?

Comment: Да, разумеется. Это адов костыль, за который разработчикам до сих пор стыдно. Это как слово-исключение в языке. Да, оно есть, но это не значит что надо все остальные слова коверкать